# How to print HTML content from a Django template in a view?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

Let's say I have a template called `index.html` with a bunch of block tags and variables and URLs. I can display it from my view using the `render()` function like so:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html", {...})
```

I would like to print the actual content that is being generated here in a normal python function. Something like this:

```
def get_html():
    html_content = some_function("index.html", {...}) # Takes in the template name and context
    print(html_content)
```

Is this possible to do using Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`render_to_string` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string). Because `render` [internally uses this function](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/shortcuts.py#L24) to build the HTML content and it simply pass it down to `HTTPResponse` class to build the appropriate response from the view.

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
rendered = render_to_string('my_template.html', {'foo': 'bar'})
```